# How wrong do I use Math.Pow(a,b) function in this C# code?

Tags: c#, math, pow

I can not find anything wrong with the following code, whence the MSVC# compiler stores NAN in "c":

```
double c = Math.Pow(-8d, 1d / 3d);
```

While I think this line should calculate -2 for "c", the compiler stores NAN in "c"?
Am i wrong about anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The power function for floating point numbers is only defined for positive base or integral exponent.  Try

```
double c = - Math.Pow(8d, 1d / 3d);
```

Actually, 1/3 can't be represented exactly as a floating point number, but needs to be rounded.  An exact real result for the rounded exponent does not even exist in theory.

Answer (score 6):

Normally, one wouldn't say that (-8)^(1/3) = -2.

Indeed it is true that (-2)^3 = -8, but powers of negative numbers are a complicated matter.

You can read more about the problem on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Negative_nth_roots):

> Neither the logarithm method nor the
>   rational exponent method can be used
>   to define a^r as a real number for a
>   negative real number a and an
>   arbitrary real number r. Indeed, er is
>   positive for every real number r, so
>   ln(a) is not defined as a real number
>   for a ≤ 0. (On the other hand,
>   arbitrary complex powers of negative
>   numbers a can be defined by choosing a
>   complex logarithm of a.)

In short, it's mathematically hard to properly define what a^r should be, when a is negative, lest one starts working with complex numbers, and therefore one in general should steer clear of trying to do that.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is an complex number: `1.0+1.732050807568877i`. .NET's Math class does not support complex numbers.

Comment: @user388360: -2 is a possible answer. Depends on a specification whether it is deemed correct or not.

Comment: I do not think it as a reasonable justification. for example one of the answers of 8^(1/3) is equal to -1+i*3^(1/2). but when we use c=Math.Pow(8d,1d/3d) we expect to get c=2 without having any hope on Math class complex support capabilities. I think the main problem arises from the algorithm which calculates the nth root of a negative number in .NET.