# Why does Math.Pow(-78.0921, -64.6294) return NaN?

Tags: c#

I have two values: `X = -78.0921` and `Y = -64.6294`. Now, when I want to compute `Math.Pow(X, Y)` it returns NaN. What should I do? How can I solve this problem?

How should I calculate this power? Is there any other function that can calculate this?...or maybe it is not defined mathematically ?

Comment: What do you expect the value to be?

Comment: It would return NaN not infinity? Similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723320/how-wrong-do-i-use-math-powa-b-function-in-this-c-sharp-code

Comment: Do you actually want the complex result? That can be done, if you really want. It seems more likely to me that you've made an error in computing your inputs though.

Comment: You want [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-78.0921%29^%28-64.6294%29)?

Comment: It isn't defined as a real number, it is complex. You can compute `-Math.Pow(78.09, -64.63)` but you can't compute `Math.Pow(-78.09, -64.63)`.

Comment: @Patashu You changed the question quite drastically and made most of the answers appear a bit daft. Perhaps next time you could update the answers as well as the question!

Comment: @David Heffernan The answers look OK to me. The comments look daft but comments are often outdated (because they can't be edited after five minutes).

Comment: @Patashu It looks stupid to be waffling on about `Infinity` now that the question makes no mention of that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've tried to compute a number that is not real.

By not real I mean, if we tried every single number between the largest number and the smallest number you can think of, none of those numbers is the solution to -78.0921 to the power of -64.6294.

In fact, no real number is the solution to -1 to the power of 0.5, or the square root of -1, and in general for a^b if a is negative and b is non-integer, **the result is not real.**

**The inability to express such a useful result in real numbers lead to the invention of complex numbers.** We say `sqrt(-1) = i`, the imaginary unit, in the complex number system - all complex numbers have a real component and an imaginary component, expressed as `a + b*i`.

In general, no negative number to a fractional power produces a real result, as it will have some component of i in it - the closer to a .5 the power is, the more i, the closer to a .0, the more real, and the path follows a circle between real and imaginary, e.g.

`-1^x = cos(pi*x)+i*sin(pi*x)`

Read more about complex numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number

---

If you wish to work with complex numbers in C#, try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex.aspx

However, unless complex numbers have some meaning in your problem domain (they are meaningful in many electrical engineering, physics and signal analysis problems, for example) it's possible that your data is wrong or your logic is wrong to be attempting to do such a thing in the first place.

Comment: I don’t think your “in general” statement is quite right. For example, `(-1)^(-1/3)`.

Comment: @rynah http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1%29%5E%28-1%2F3%29 , x component is `cos(-pi/3)`, y component is `sin(-pi/3)`. Looks OK to me.

Comment: Its real root is also `-1`, though?

Comment: @rynah You are reading the section titled 'All 3rd roots of -1/1:'. It is a property of -1 that one of its 3rd roots is -1, not of (-1)^(-1/3) (which is another of them)

Comment: The complex is too complex that I use it's pow func that not equal math.pow.Complex.Pow(2, 2)!=Math.Pow(2,2)

Answer (score 14):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx) states that the returned value for those inputs is `NaN`.

> x < 0 but not NegativeInfinity; y is not an integer, NegativeInfinity, or PositiveInfinity: returns **NaN**

The reason that `NaN` is returned is that the function is not well-defined for your input values. The Wikipedia article on [Exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents_with_negative_bases) covers this topic.

Comment: Here: [Math.Pow Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx)

Comment: It is indeed NaN for these numbers.

Comment: x < 0 but not NegativeInfinity; y is not an integer, NegativeInfinity, or PositiveInfinity.

Comment: The documentation doesn't give any insight as to why is it undefined for those values? (-a)^(-b) is simply -1.0/(a^b) right? Is there a good reason it has to return NaN?

Comment: Ah, i was thinking about -(a)^(-b) which is -1.0/(a^b) whereas (-a)^(-b) is in fact complex and should of course be a NaN.

Comment: @AndersForsgren https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents_with_negative_bases

Answer (score 7):

I think you mean that it returns `NaN` because your input matches the following:

> x < 0 but not NegativeInfinity; y is not an integer, NegativeInfinity, or PositiveInfinity

Which is correct, as per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx).

Comment: Well Thnx a lot for your answers. Actually I have no benefit from complex numbers in my project. There is a problem with the formula that I am using. It is strange definitely. These days there are a lot of papers accepted by journals even thogh they are rubbish and just cheating. The formula that I am using I found it in a paper. Anyway thnx to all for answering

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I used for (native C# library `System.Numerics`):

> `Complex.Pow(x, y).Real;`

The result is the same as:

```
double checkSquareRoot(double x, double y)
        {
            var result = Math.Pow(x, y);

            if (x > 0)
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return -1 * Math.Pow(-x, y);
            }
        }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and handled as shown below, you have to adjust the min and max values as needed, in my case they are 0 and 10.

```
      double alpha =  FastMath.pow(weight, parameters.getAlpha());
      if(alpha == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) {
          alpha = 0d;
      } 
      if(alpha == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
          alpha = 10d;
      } 

      double beta = FastMath.pow(1d / distanceMatrix[row][column],
           parameters.getBeta());
      if(beta == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) {
          beta = 0d;
      } 
      if(beta == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
          beta = 10d;
      }
```

Comment: Can you give FastMath ?

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/util/FastMath.html

Comment: Thx,I will look it .Can FastMath solve FastMath.pow(-10,1.0/3)?

Answer (score 0):

It is another weak point in C#. We know that cubic root of -125 is equal to -5, but the result of `Console.Write(Math.Pow(-125,1.0/3));` is NaN.
Perhaps you should try this:

```
if (x>0) {
  Console.Write(Math.Pow(x,y));
}
else if (x<0) {
  double x = Abs(x);
  double z = Math.Pow(x,y);
  if (y%2==0)
       Console.Write(z);
  else
       Console.Write(-z);
}
```

Comment: I try use Math.Pow(-10,2) and use you answer but it's incorrect.

Comment: Ohh.. I missed the power of even number and power of odd number scenario. Now It's fixed.